# Access Violation with wxPythons CallLater

Tags: python, wxpython, tkinter

I'm attempting to convert some of my code from Tkinter to wxPython. Currently I'm trying to create a function that continually loops, updating the time. However, I have run into some problems. Whenever I close the program, a window pops up, and gives me the following warning.

```
Access violation at address 1E058497 in module 'python26.dll'. Read of address 00000008.
```

This then causes my IDE (PyScripter) to freeze and crash. I think it may be trying to call the function after the program has been destroyed. This then causes it to access an unavailable location in memory, causing all sorts of fun. Any help would be appreciated.

Snippet:

```
def tick (self):
    ''' Continually updates the time. '''

    TimeStr = '%I:%M %S %p'
    DateStr = '%A, %B %d, %Y'

    Time = time.strftime(TimeStr)
    Date = time.strftime(DateStr)

    self.TimeDate =  Time + '\t\t' + Date

    self.ST.SetLabel(self.TimeDate)

    wx.CallLater(1000, self.tick)
```

In the Tkinter version **wx.CallLater(1000, self.tick)** was substituted with **.after(1000, self.tick)**, If that helps.

**Edit:**

I tried it in IDLE and it seemed to work. However, no luck in PyScripter.

Comment: do you call this tick method before MainLoop() ? do you terminate the loop call when MainLoop is exited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is:

(1)
`self.scheduled_call = wx.CallLater(1000, self.tick)`

during program close, cancel via, xxx.scheduled_call.??????()
I forgot the exact name of the method, please check wx docs.

OR if the above is not possible

(2) set a boolean variable in the instance, that controls the call.
`if self.var: wx.CallLater(1000, self.tick)`

var is True when program is running
during program close, set xxx.var to False